# pip install environment_kernels Not Working for Switching Conda Environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

Even after I install the kernal package by calling `pip install environment_kernels` in anaconda prompt, I'm still not able to change the environment in my Jupyter notebook.

This is how it looks like on the top right corner of a ipynb file when I click into

[image]

And here's what shows up when I click Kernel tab to try to switch to another environment.

[image]

And I'm honestly so confused why I don't even have a conda tab on the main page.
[image]

Can somebody help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to set the display-name, then you can see it in change kernal

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name yourenvnamehere --display-name "the display name you want there"
```

Comment: Display name as in "Python 3" ?

Comment: yes, you can give a name easy for yourself to distinguish

Comment: Ohhhhh, I see how it works now. It was just added perfectly! Wait, how do I remove a certain display-name then? I think I accidentally installed two different environments with the same name.

Comment: try this: jupyter kernelspec list, and: jupyter kernelspec remove <kernel_name>

Comment: I just figured it out from another post, which was exactly the same as what you said. It worked by `jupyter kernelspec remove <kernel_name>`